# Filter MongoDB query to find documents only if a field in a list of objects is not empty

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB document structure like following:

**Structure**

```
{
    "stores": [
        {
            "items": [
                {
                    "feedback": [],
                    "item_category": "101",
                    "item_id": "10"
                },
                {
                    "feedback": [],
                    "item_category": "101",
                    "item_id": "11"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "items": [
                {
                    "feedback": [],
                    "item_category": "101",
                    "item_id": "10"
                },
                {
                    "feedback": ["A feedback"],
                    "item_category": "101",
                    "item_id": "11"
                },
                {
                    "feedback": [],
                    "item_category": "101",
                    "item_id": "12"
                },
                {
                    "feedback": [],
                    "item_category": "102",
                    "item_id": "13"
                },
                {
                    "feedback": [],
                    "item_category": "102",
                    "item_id": "14"
                }
            ],
            "store_id": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a single document in a collection. Some field are deleted to produce minimal representation of the data.

What I want is to get items only if the `feedback` field in the `items` array is not empty. The expected result is:

**Expected result**

```
{
    "stores": [
        {
            "items": [
                {
                    "feedback": ["A feedback"],
                    "item_category": "101",
                    "item_id": "11"
                }
            ],
            "store_id": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I tried based on examples in [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch), which I think pretty same situation, but it didn't work. What's wrong with my query, isn't it the same situation in *zipcode search* example in the link? It returns everything like in the first JSON code, *Structure*:

**What I tried**

```py
query = {
    'date': {'$gte': since, '$lte': until},
    'stores.items': {"$elemMatch": {"feedback": {"$ne": []}}}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you've store_id in first object of stores array as well ? Please mention your mongoDB version..

Comment: Did it work or still having issues ?

Comment: I tried it but still having issues actually. I will inform you more. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([
{ $match: { 'date': { '$gte': since, '$lte': until }, 'stores.items': { "$elemMatch": { "feedback": { "$ne": [] } } } } },
{ $unwind: '$stores' },
{ $match: { 'stores.items': { "$elemMatch": { "feedback": { "$ne": [] } } } } },
{ $unwind: '$stores.items' },
{ $match: { 'stores.items.feedback': { "$ne": [] } } },
{ $group: { _id: { _id: '$_id', store_id: '$stores.store_id' }, items: { $push: '$stores.items' } } },
{ $project: { _id: '$_id._id', store_id: '$_id.store_id', items: 1 } },
{ $group: { _id: '$_id', stores: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
{ $project: { 'stores._id': 0 } }
])
```

We've all these stages as you need to operate on an array of arrays, this query is written assuming you're dealing with a large set of data, Since you're filtering on dates just in case if your documents size is way less after first `$match` then you can avoid following `$match` stage which is in between two `$unwind`'s.

**Ref 's :**

[$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html),
[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html),
[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html),
[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This aggregate query gets the needed result (using the provided sample document and run from the *mongo shell*):

```
db.stores.aggregate( [
  { $unwind: "$stores" },
  { $unwind: "$stores.items" },
  { $addFields: { feedbackExists: { $gt: [ { $size: "$stores.items.feedback" }, 0 ] } } },
  { $match: { feedbackExists: true } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, feedbackExists: 0 } }
] )
```